# Neo4j count increases execution time substantially and runs out of memory

Tags: neo4j, count

I am using Neo4j to store data regarding movie ratings. I would like to count the number of movies that two users both rated. When running the query

```
match (a:User)-[:RATED]->(b:Movie)<-[:RATED]-(c:User) return a,b,c limit 1000
```

it completes in less than a second, however running

```
match (a:User)-[:RATED]->(b:Movie)<-[:RATED]-(c:User) return a,count(b),c limit 1000
```

the database can't finish the query as the heap runs out of memory, which I have set as 4gb. Am I using the count function properly? I don't understand how the performance between these two queries can differ so significantly.

Comment: are you specifically looking for the two user data? or you want to know all the movie counts that any two users rated?

Comment: What is the count of User, movie nodes and relationships?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MissingNumber has a good explanation of what's going on. When you do aggregations, the whole set has to be considered to do the aggregations correctly, and that must happen before the LIMIT, and this is taking a huge toll on your heap space.

As an alternate in your case, you can try the following:

```
match (a:User)-[:RATED]->()<-[:RATED]-(c:User)
with DISTINCT a, c
where id(a) < id(c)
limit 1000
match (a)-[:RATED]->(m:Movie)<-[:RATED]-(c)
with a, c, count(m) as moviesRated
return a, moviesRated, c
```

By moving the LIMIT up before the aggregation, but using DISTINCT instead to ensure we only deal with a pair of nodes in this pattern once (and apply a predicate based on graph ids to ensure we never deal with mirrored results), we should get a more efficient query. Then for each of those 1000 pairs of a and c, we expand out the pattern again and get the actual counts.

Comment: I have also noticed that it is a good idea to add the following filter to avoid duplicate results

(a:User)-[:RATED]->()<-[:RATED]-(c:User)
WHERE id(a) > id(c)

Comment: Thanks, I later figured out that I had a misconception about what "limit" was doing. I thought it only ran the query until the limit of queries reached. I wasn't sure how to apply the limit before the aggregate function, thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into a similar similar situation and solved this using the following approach, this will be applicable to you.

I used a data set having:
(TYPE_S) - 380 nodes
(TYPE_N) - 800000 nodes
[:S_realation_N] - 5600000 relations

Query one :

```
match (s:TYPE_S)-[]-(n:TYPE_N) return s, n limit 10
```

This took 2 milli-seconds.

As soon as 10 patterns(relations) are found in db, neo4j just returns result.

Query two :

```
match (s:TYPE_S)-[]-(n:TYPE_N) return s, sum(n.value) limit 10
```

This took ~4000 milli-seconds.

This might look like a query as fast as last one. But surely it won’t be as fast as the previous one because of aggregation involved.

**Reason**:

For the query to aggregate over pattern, Neo4j has to load all the paths that matches given pattern (these are way more than 10 or given limit here and will be 5600000 as per my dataset) into ram  before performing aggregation. Later this aggregation is performed over 10 full records S_TYPE nodes, so this falls into specified return format with given limit now. Rest of the relations in the ram are then flushed. Which means for a moment ran is loaded with lot data which will later be ignored due to limit.

***So to optimize runtimes and memory usage here you have to avoid part of query which leads to loading data which will later be ignored.***

This is how I optimized it:

```
match (s:TYPE_S) where ((s)-[]-(:TYPE_N)) 
with collect(s)[0..10] as s_list
unwind s_list as s
match (s)-[]-(n:TYPE_N) return s, sum(n.value)
```

This took 64 milli-seconds.

Now neo4j first shortlists 10 nodes of type  TYPE_S which have relations with TYPE_S, and then matches the pattern with these nodes and get their data.  This should work and run better than query2 since you are loading a limited set of records in to ram.

You could use this similar way to build your query, by shorting 1000 (a,b) distinct user pairs and then perform aggregations on them.
But this approach will fail in case where need to order by aggregation.

Reason for your query to run out of memory is because you are using 4 gb ram and running a query that may load a lot of combinational data  into ram(this may sometimes be more than size of you db due multiplicity of data combinations defined in you patterns, in your case even if you have 50 unique users, you have 50*49 possible unique combinations of patterns that can loaded in to ram). Also other transactions and queries running in parallel could also impact.